# Html table overlapping in mobile browser when sending email with same subject from c# code

Tags: c#, html, email

I am sending emails to our users about updated score after each interval of game. For this i am sending email with same subject same message body just updated interval score. so when i open my email in mobile browser  it will creates group of emails and overlaps my mail format when i send single mail it will display correctly. but not display correctly in  grouping. i think it group it because same from email id. it display correctly on desktop browser.
so how do i solve it, please help me.

```
private static StringBuilder createstringformat_forsendingMail(DataTable dtTeamscoreDB, int Qtrno, string Quater)
{
    StringBuilder strTable = new StringBuilder();
    string strnotes = "",str;
    int flag = 0;
    bool OTAdded = false;

    try
    {
        string strTeam1 = "", strTeam2 = "", strOTteam1score = "", strOTteam2score = "", strFinalScore1 = "", strFinalScore2="";
        strTeam1 = dtTeamscoreDB.Rows[0]["team1name"].ToString();
        strTeam2 = dtTeamscoreDB.Rows[0]["team2name"].ToString();

        DataTable dtTeam = new DataTable();

        dtTeam.Columns.Add("Qtr");
        dtTeam.Columns.Add("Teamscore1");
        dtTeam.Columns.Add("Teamscore2");

        for (int i = 1; i <= Qtrno; i++)
        {
            DataRow dtrow = dtTeam.NewRow();
            dtrow["Qtr"] = "Qtr" + i;
            //dtTeam.Rows.Add[i]["Qtr"] = "Qtr" + i;
            for (int dt = 0; dt < dtTeamscoreDB.Rows.Count; dt++)
            {
                if (Convert.ToInt32(dtTeamscoreDB.Rows[dt]["interval_id"].ToString()) == i)
                {
                    dtrow["Teamscore1"] = dtTeamscoreDB.Rows[dt]["team1score"].ToString();
                    dtrow["Teamscore2"] = dtTeamscoreDB.Rows[dt]["team2score"].ToString();
                }

                if (dtTeamscoreDB.Rows[dt]["interval_name"].ToString() == "OT")
                {
                    strOTteam1score = dtTeamscoreDB.Rows[dt]["team1score"].ToString();
                    strOTteam2score = dtTeamscoreDB.Rows[dt]["team2score"].ToString();
                }
                if (dtTeamscoreDB.Rows[dt]["interval_name"].ToString() == "F")
                {
                    strFinalScore1 = dtTeamscoreDB.Rows[dt]["team1score"].ToString();
                    strFinalScore2 = dtTeamscoreDB.Rows[dt]["team2score"].ToString();
                }
            }

            dtTeam.Rows.Add(dtrow);
            dtTeam.AcceptChanges();
        }

        //if OT is not present then add blank 
        DataRow dtOTrow = dtTeam.NewRow();
        dtOTrow["Qtr"] = "OT";
        dtOTrow["Teamscore1"] = strOTteam1score;
        dtOTrow["Teamscore2"] = strOTteam2score;
        dtTeam.Rows.Add(dtOTrow);
        if (Qtrno == 9)
        {
            DataRow dtOTrow1 = dtTeam.NewRow();
            dtOTrow1["Qtr"] = "F";
            dtOTrow1["Teamscore1"] = strFinalScore1;
            dtOTrow1["Teamscore2"] = strFinalScore2;
            dtTeam.Rows.Add(dtOTrow1);
        }
        dtTeam.AcceptChanges();

        strTable.Append("<pre><table style='width:480px;border-Top: 1px solid #000000;' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' >");
        strTable.Append("<tr><td style='border-left: 1px solid #000000;border-right: 1px solid #000000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;' align='center'>&nbsp;" + dtTeamscoreDB.Rows[0]["team1name"].ToString() + "</td>");
        strTable.Append("<td style='border-right: 1px solid #000000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;' align='center'>&nbsp;" + dtTeamscoreDB.Rows[0]["team2name"].ToString() + "</td></tr>");
        strTable.Append("<tr><td align='center' style='border-left: 1px solid #000000;border-right: 1px solid #000000;'>" + dtTeamscoreDB.Rows[dtTeamscoreDB.Rows.Count - 1]["team1score"].ToString() + "</td>");
        strTable.Append("<td align='center' style='border-right: 1px solid #000000;'>" + dtTeamscoreDB.Rows[dtTeamscoreDB.Rows.Count - 1]["team2score"].ToString() + "</td></tr>");
        strTable.Append("<tr><td colspan='2' style='border-top: 1px solid #000000;'>&nbsp;</td> </tr>");
        strTable.Append("<tr><td colspan='2'>");

        strTable.Append("<table cellpadding='0' border='0' cellspacing='0' style='width:480px;border: 1px solid #000000;'>");
        strTable.Append("<tr><td style='border-right:1px solid #000000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;'><b>&nbsp;</b></td>");
        //strTable.Append("<td style='border-right: 1px solid #000000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;'><b>&nbsp;" + strTeam1 + "</b></td>");
        //strTable.Append("<td style='border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;'><b>&nbsp;" + strTeam2 + "</b></td></tr>");
        for (int i = 1; i <= Qtrno; i++)
        {
            if (Qtrno == 9)
            {
                strTable.Append("<td style='border-right: 1px solid #000000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;'><b>&nbsp; " + i + "</b></td>");

                //strTable.Append("<td style='border-right: 1px solid #000000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;'>&nbsp;" + dtTeam.Rows[i - 1]["Teamscore1"].ToString() + "</td>");
                //strTable.Append("<td style='border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;'>&nbsp;" + dtTeam.Rows[i - 1]["Teamscore2"].ToString() + "</td></tr>");
            }
            else
            {
                if (Quater == "Q")
                {
                    strTable.Append("<td style='border-right: 1px solid #000000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;'><b>&nbsp; " + i + "</b></td>");
                    //strTable.Append("<td style='border-right: 1px solid #000000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;'>&nbsp;" + dtTeam.Rows[i - 1]["Teamscore1"].ToString() + "</td>");
                    //strTable.Append("<td style='border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;'>&nbsp;" + dtTeam.Rows[i - 1]["Teamscore2"].ToString() + "</td></tr>");
                }
                else
                {
                    strTable.Append("<td style='border-right: 1px solid #000000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;'><b>&nbsp;" + i + "</b></td>");
                    //strTable.Append("<td style='border-right: 1px solid #000000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;'>&nbsp;" + dtTeam.Rows[i - 1]["Teamscore1"].ToString() + "</td>");
                    //strTable.Append("<td style='border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;'>&nbsp;" + dtTeam.Rows[i - 1]["Teamscore2"].ToString() + "</td></tr>");
                }
            }
        }
        if (Qtrno == 9)
        {
            strTable.Append("<td style='border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;border-Right: 1px solid #000000;'><b>&nbsp;Extra</b></td>");
            strTable.Append("<td style='border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;'><b>&nbsp;F</b></td></tr>");
        }
        else
        {
            strTable.Append("<td style='border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;'><b>&nbsp;OT</b></td></tr>");
        }
        string strTeam1Row = "<tr><td style='border-right: 1px solid #000000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;'><b>&nbsp;" + strTeam1 + "</b></td>";
        string strTeam2Row = "<tr><td style='border-right: 1px solid #000000;'><b>&nbsp;" + strTeam2 + "</b></td>";
        string QTRfinal = "";
        if (Qtrno == 9)
        {
            QTRfinal = "F";
        }
        else
        {
            QTRfinal = "OT";
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < dtTeam.Rows.Count; j++)
        {
            if (dtTeam.Rows[j]["QTR"].ToString() != QTRfinal)
            {
                if (dtTeam.Columns[1].ColumnName.ToString() == "Teamscore1")
                {
                    strTeam1Row = strTeam1Row + "<td style='border-right: 1px solid #000000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;'>&nbsp;" + dtTeam.Rows[j]["Teamscore1"].ToString() + "</td>";
                }

                if (dtTeam.Columns[2].ColumnName.ToString() == "Teamscore2")
                {
                    strTeam2Row = strTeam2Row + "<td style='border-right: 1px solid #000000;'>&nbsp;" + dtTeam.Rows[j]["Teamscore2"].ToString() + "</td>";
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                if (dtTeam.Columns[1].ColumnName.ToString() == "Teamscore1")
                {
                    strTeam1Row = strTeam1Row + "<td style='border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;'>&nbsp;" + dtTeam.Rows[j]["Teamscore1"].ToString() + "</td>";
                }

                if (dtTeam.Columns[2].ColumnName.ToString() == "Teamscore2")
                {
                    strTeam2Row = strTeam2Row + "<td >&nbsp;" + dtTeam.Rows[j]["Teamscore2"].ToString() + "</td>";
                }
            }
        }
        //strTeam1Row = strTeam1Row + "<td style='border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;'>&nbsp;" + dtTeam.Rows[0]["Teamscore1"].ToString() + "</td></tr>";
        //strTeam2Row = strTeam2Row + "<td>&nbsp;" + dtTeam.Rows[0]["Teamscore2"].ToString() + "</td></tr>";

            //for (int T = 0; T < dtTeamscoreDB.Rows.Count; T++)
            //{
            //    if (dtTeam.Rows[T]["interval_name"].ToString().ToUpper() == "OT")
            //    {

            //    }
            //    //else
            //    //{
            //    //    strTeam1Row = strTeam1Row + "<td style='border-right:1px solid #000000'>&nbsp;</td></tr>";
            //    //    strTeam2Row = strTeam2Row + "<td>&nbsp;</td></tr>";
            //    //}
            //}

            strTable.Append(strTeam1Row);
            strTable.Append(strTeam2Row);

        for (int T = 0; T < dtTeamscoreDB.Rows.Count; T++)
        {
            if (dtTeamscoreDB.Rows[T]["notes"].ToString() != " " || dtTeamscoreDB.Rows[T]["notes"].ToString() !=null)
            {
                int interval_id = Convert.ToInt32(dtTeamscoreDB.Rows[T]["interval_id"].ToString());
                if (dtTeamscoreDB.Rows[T]["interval_name"].ToString() != "OT")
                {
                    if (Qtrno == 9)
                    { 
                        if (dtTeamscoreDB.Rows[T]["interval_name"].ToString() == "F")
                        {
                            strnotes = strnotes + "F" + " : " + dtTeamscoreDB.Rows[T]["notes"].ToString() + "<br/>";

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            strnotes = strnotes + "Inn " + interval_id + ": " + dtTeamscoreDB.Rows[T]["notes"].ToString() + "<br/>";
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (Quater == "Q")
                            strnotes = strnotes + "Qtr " + interval_id + ": " + dtTeamscoreDB.Rows[T]["notes"].ToString() + "<br/>";
                        else
                            strnotes = strnotes + "Game " + interval_id + ": " + dtTeamscoreDB.Rows[T]["notes"].ToString() + "<br/>";

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (Qtrno == 9)
                    {
                        strnotes = strnotes + "Extra: " + dtTeamscoreDB.Rows[T]["notes"].ToString() + "<br/>";

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        strnotes = strnotes + "OT: " + dtTeamscoreDB.Rows[T]["notes"].ToString() + "<br/>";
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        strTable.Append("</table></td></td>");
        strTable.Append("<tr><td colspan='2'>&nbsp;</td></tr>");

        strTable.Append("<tr><td colspan='2' style='border: 1px solid #000000;'><b>&nbsp;Notes:</b></td></tr>");
        strTable.Append("<tr><td colspan='2' style='border-left: 1px solid #000000;border-right: 1px solid #000000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;'>" + strnotes + "</td></tr></table><br/></pre>");
strTable.Append("<table><tr><td style='Font-Size:10px; align:center; color:Red;'>We want to thank our generous sponsors for supporting us and making this event possible.</td></tr>");
strTable.Append("<tr><td  align='center'><img src='" + strimageurl + "' alt='Our Partners' /></td></tr></table>");
    return strTable;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}

public static bool sendmailMultipleuser(string strFromEmailid, string strToEmailid, string strSubject, string strMessage)
{
    bool mailFlag = false;
    try
    {
        SmtpClient smtpclient = new SmtpClient();
        //EncryptedUid = ObjUtility.EncryptString(Userid);            
        MailAddress FromUser = new MailAddress(strFromEmailid);
        //MailAddress ToUser = new MailAddress(strToEmailid);

        MailMessage Mailmsg = new MailMessage();
        Mailmsg.From = FromUser;
        string[] Toemailid = strToEmailid.Split(',');
        for (int i = 0; i < Toemailid.Length; i++)
        {
            Mailmsg.To.Add(Toemailid[i].ToString());
        }

        Mailmsg.Subject = strSubject;
        Mailmsg.IsBodyHtml = true;
        Mailmsg.Body = strMessage;

        smtpclient.Send(Mailmsg);
        mailFlag = true;
        return mailFlag;
    }
    catch
    {
        return mailFlag;
    }
}
```

The above code i have created to dynamically create message and send that message through email. please help me.